# form_error displaying "xss_clean"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I work with CodeIgniter. I need to make multiple array in my form and sort the form by the name.

My html :

```
<input type="text" value="<?= set_value('joueur[0][nom]') ?>" name="joueur[0][nom]">
```

My php :

```
foreach ($_POST as $form => $listPersons)
{

    foreach($listPersons as $numPerson => $listFields)
    {

        foreach ($listFields as $field => $value)
        {

             $fieldName = "{$form}[{$numPerson}][{$field}]";
             /* in switch case ...*/
                default:
                    $this   ->form_validation
                            ->set_rules($fieldName, 'Tous les champs sont obligatoires', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                break;
        }
    }
}


        }

    }

}
```

And the var_dump :

```
string(18) "
(xss_clean)
"
```

My input value is "hello" or other correct string. I don't understand why the form error return (xss_clean) :-/

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you loaded the security library in your controller ?

Comment: What is in your Controller?

Comment: Thank you Asim Shahzad, it's this : Just load the security helper.
Can I know why I've lost my reputation ? For not do the bad thing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work now. The xss_clean need to load the security Helper, and I had forgotten. You can load the security helper in the config/autoload.php or the controller.